# Direct Access to database from native app (any security issues?)

Tags: database, security

I'm new to databases and It's been almost a month I'm working with databases (mostly with MongoDB which is a NoSQL database and I'm loving it :D)

What I am wondering is the security risks you take when you do a direct access to database from let's say a native iOS app.

I know a popular way to this is web service though.

Thanks,

Peyman

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080067/should-i-access-mongodb-directly/21275918 for some more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there're 2 risks obviously:

1. sql injection.
2. How to deal with the db password. Just put the plain text in your
   config or connection strings?

Comment: Aha that hardcoding password somewhere in the code made me ask this question. I am right now working with Web Service...not sure if it's the best way though.

Answer (score 1):

+1 on password protection or connection strings.  Not to mention that your firewall would have to allow every ip through on your database port.  People use web services for a reason...in my opinion, don't even consider this an option